# Interpreting $R^2$, F-statistic & p-value of a model

Tags: r, regression, p-value

From p. 277 of *R Cookbook*:

> Let's say I have a R model `lm(formula = y ~ u + v + w)` and the
>   `Summary()` shows:
>
> ```
> Multiple R-Squared: 0.4981, Adjust R-Squared: 0.4402 F-statistic:
> 8.603 on 3 and 26 DF, p-value: 0.0003915
> ```
>
> Using Adjusted `r-Squared` I can say that my model explains 44.02% of
>   the variance of `y` with the remaining 55.98 unexplained.

Question:  **Does the associated F-statistic (with the p-value being < .05) tell me:**

1. the model, in general, is significant (not taking into account other values from Summary)
2. the model is significant in explaining the 44.02% variance (adjusted r-squared)

Comment: How did you arrive at 3, and 26  d.f.?

Answer (score 15):

The F-statistics tells you if the model fits the data better than the mean. Or, in other words, if $H_0:\;R^2=0$ should be rejected.

See: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems)

To illustrate that the formula given in the link is indeed used by `summary.lm`:

```
x1 <- 1:10
set.seed(42)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
y <- x1+2*x2+rnorm(10)

fit0 <- lm(y~1)
fit1 <- lm(y~x1+x2)

summary(fit1)
#F-statistic:  14.1 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.003507 

RSS0 <- sum(residuals(fit0)^2)
RSS1 <- sum(residuals(fit1)^2)

Fvalue <- (RSS0-RSS1)/(3-1)/RSS1*(10-3)
#14.10014
pf(Fvalue,2,7,lower.tail=FALSE)
#0.00350697
```

Comment: The  question  concerns about the chisquared test of variability and does not ask for the significance of mean.

Comment: My answer does not say anything about significance of the mean.

Comment: The two formulations are different. I think, one (Ist) imbibes - so called random effects and second is based on on (true )(fi xed- effects model.itmaybe noted that the two shoud yield same results. To my knowlege, first one model acts on assumption of random effects assumption and second one under fixed effeccts assumption. Therefore, I am not conviced your structure and proof.

Comment: Sorry, but both OP's model and the so-called Null model y ~ 1 are pure fixed effects models.

Comment: fit1 <- lm(y~x1+x2)
please explain briefly. thanks for your valuable response. I am a halfbaked statistics worker.

Comment: This maybe helpful.A Memo on How to Use the Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm fo…
https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661_Fall2012/homework/hw5_LM...